# Google Maps Event - AddListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ola, gostaria de saber se alguem tem noção de como retornar um evento GLOBAL de qualquer coisa feita no mapa para ser interpretada com CASE! Abaixo como utilizo elas hoje.

> google.maps.event.addListener(map, "**click**", function(event) {

No caso não queria definir o exemplo do CLICK e sim analisar depois, algo do tipo:

> google.maps.event.addListener(map, function(event) {

Ai posteriormente analisar em CASE qual evento que veio para tratar com CASE e BREAK pois utilizo 3 eventos no mapa, e quando os 3 são executados simultaneamente acaba ficando 3 informações no mapa e esta sobrecarregando quando junta muitas informações.

se alguem souber de algum metodo pois ja tentei de tudo e ainda não consegui.

Obrigado desde ja.

Comment: Eu desconheço esse controle de *múltiplos eventos*, acredito que só dá pra controlar um por vez mesmo. Não ficou muito claro o que seriam essas "muitas informações" que você falou mas sendo um marcador ou o texto de um _infowindow_ você poderia limpar e redesenhar sempre que um dos eventos for chamado (é feio mas funciona :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois que comentei fiquei pensando em uma solução melhor.. você pode usar a ideia de limpar/redesenhar mas usando um *timeout* pra diminuir o número de redesenho.

```
var EventoDisparado = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  //código
  window.setTimeout("MuitasInformacoes", 1000);
});

function initMap(){
  //código
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "evt_01", function(event) { 
    EventoDisparado = true;
  }); 
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "evt_02", function(event) { 
    EventoDisparado = true;
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "evt_03", function(event) { 
    EventoDisparado = true;
  });
}

function MuitasInformacoes() {
  if (EventoDisparado) {
    //TODO: add as info
  }
  EventoDisparado = false;
}
```

Comment: Peguei a sua ideia e fiz umas alterações e funcionou perfeitamente. A unica coisa que fiz de mudança foi quando disparar um evento ele altera este valor, e as funções que fazem adição de marcador / polylines ele verifica esta informação e aborta caso for necessário!

Tambem não usei delay pois so quero que carregue uma vez as informações.